# Does mysql running normally?

Tags: php, mysql, bash, networking, port

i have a question about checking remote mysql server.

How I can check, mysql server running normally or  occurred an error on any remote web page. Is there a way to tell with php or bash?

For ex:

```
$ nc -z -w 1 example.com 3306
> Connection to example.com 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

I dont want to use the port data in method. because this is changeable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having the mysql port open for public seems to be dangerous. You're better off with using a php intermediary, as follows:

```
<?php
  // some code that connects to the database and return OK when the database is 
  // up and running, returns ERROR when problems arise
?>
```

The you can do a wget or curl to get the status and act on it.

Moreover, you could return more than OK or ERROR; send e-mails, ...

Comment: Do wget and curl get me mysql status? i know, they are return only http status? is there any method for mysql status?